# How to add a new column with maximum value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with 2 columns `tag` and `value`.

I want to add a new column that contains the `max` of `value` column. (It will be the same value for every row).

I tried to do something as follows, but it didn't work.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("max",max($"value"))
```

How to add the `max` column to the dataset?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do it (one you already know from the other answer). I avoid `collect` since it's not really needed.

Here is the dataset with the maximum value 3 appearing twice.

```
val tags = Seq(
  ("tg1", 1), ("tg2", 2), ("tg1", 3), ("tg4", 4), ("tg3", 3)
).toDF("tag", "value")
scala> tags.show
+---+-----+
|tag|value|
+---+-----+
|tg1|    1|
|tg2|    2|
|tg1|    3| <-- maximum value
|tg4|    4|
|tg3|    3| <-- another maximum value
+---+-----+
```

### Cartesian Join With "Max" Dataset

I'm going to use a cartesian join of the `tags` and a single-row dataset with the maximum value.

```
val maxDF = tags.select(max("value") as "max")
scala> maxDF.show
+---+
|max|
+---+
|  4|
+---+
val solution = tags.crossJoin(maxDF)
scala> solution.show
+---+-----+---+
|tag|value|max|
+---+-----+---+
|tg1|    1|  4|
|tg2|    2|  4|
|tg1|    3|  4|
|tg4|    4|  4|
|tg3|    3|  4|
+---+-----+---+
```

I'm not worried about the cartesian join here since it's just a single-row dataset.

### Windowed Aggregation

My favorite windowed aggregation fits this problem so nicely. On the other hand, I don't really think that'd be the most effective approach due to the number of partitions in use, i.e. just 1, which gives the worst possible parallelism.

The trick is to use the aggregation function `max` over an empty window specification that informs Spark SQL to use all rows in any order.

```
val solution = tags.withColumn("max", max("value") over ())
scala> solution.show
18/05/31 21:59:40 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+---+-----+---+
|tag|value|max|
+---+-----+---+
|tg1|    1|  4|
|tg2|    2|  4|
|tg1|    3|  4|
|tg4|    4|  4|
|tg3|    3|  4|
+---+-----+---+
```

Please note the warning that says it all.

> WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.

I would not use this approach given the other solutions and am leaving it here for educational purposes.

Comment: Neat, I didn't realize you could do max in a select.  Also, the joining the result on is a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the maximum value of a columns for all rows, you are going to need to compare all the rows in some form.  That means doing an an aggregation.  withColumn only operates on a single row so you have no way to get the DataFrame max value.

The easiest way to do this is like below:

```
val data = Seq(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3), ("d", 4))
val df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF("name", "value")

// first is an action, so this will execute spark stages to compute the value
val maxValue = df.groupBy().agg(max($"value")).first.getInt(0)

// Now you can add it to your original DF
val updatedDF = df.withColumn("max", lit(maxValue))

updatedDF.show
```

There is also one alternative to this that might be a little faster.  If you don't need the max value until the end of your processsing (after you have already run a spark action) you can compute it by writing your own Spark Acccumulator instead that gathers the value while doing whatever other Spark Action work you have requested.

Comment: That's not true _"withColumn only operates on a single row so you have no way to get the DataFrame max value."_ as windowed aggregation would do that with ease.

Comment: Good point.  Would the windowing function method compute local max's per partition before combining, or would it pull all records to a single partition first?

Comment: See my answer that gives the answer to your question (in short: no, there'll be a single partition).

Answer (score 0):

Max column value as additional column by window function

```
val tags = Seq(
   ("tg1", 1), ("tg2", 2), ("tg1", 3), ("tg4", 4), ("tg3", 3)
).toDF("tag", "value")
scala> tags.show
+---+-----+
|tag|value|
+---+-----+
|tg1|    1|
|tg2|    2|
|tg1|    3|
|tg4|    4|
|tg3|    3|
+---+-----+
scala> tags.withColumn("max", max("value").over(Window.partitionBy(lit("1")))).show
+---+-----+---+
|tag|value|max|
+---+-----+---+
|tg1|    1|  4|
|tg2|    2|  4|
|tg1|    3|  4|
|tg4|    4|  4|
|tg3|    3|  4|
+---+-----+---+
```